# when is the suffix 边/面 required?

Tags: grammar, mandarin, usage, difference, syntax

I have learnt location words such as 上/下/前/后etc. and understand they can modify a noun such as -桌子上，宿舍前 . I also know the suffix 边 or 面 can be added (doesn't really change the meaning). When do i **need** to use the suffix? 
When do i use 上 and when do i use 上边/上面? In the next sentences, I just wrote the mono-syllabic location word, but the answers say the suffix is needed, then others I didn't need to put the suffix.

1. 中文楼右就是图书馆  (should be 右边/右面)
2. 人文楼在行政楼后吗？ (should be 后边/后面)
3. 我办公室就在新阅览室下 (should be 下边/下面)

Answer (score 1):

see grammar, [Difference between location nouns and place/position nouns, 方位词 vs 处所词](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/difference-between-location-nouns-and-place-position-nouns-%e6%96%b9%e4%bd%8d%e8%af%8d-vs-%e5%a4%84%e6%89%80%e8%af%8d/31378#31378)

additionally 汉语语法基础，第一章 词法 第一节 名词 ２。４附：方位词 方位词是具有助词性质的名词。从意义方面说，它具有一定的意义-----表示方位；但从语法方面说，它的用途又和一般的名词不同。方位词一般不单独用，有的甚至根本不能自由运用，总是附在名词后边，或者同别的方位词结合成一个表示时间或处所的名词。鉴于这种情况，把方位词列入名词，但是又不等同看待算作名词的附类。
常用的方位词有以下这些：

东 西 南 北 上 下 左 右 里 前 后 边 面 头 外 中 间 内

这些单纯的方位词还可以同＂以＂或者＂之＂构成合成的方位词。如：

以上 以下 以东 以西 以外 以内 之中 之间 之内 之上 之下 之外

方位词的用途主要有两个：１。同别的成分结合在一起，构成表示时间或处所的名词。如：东边 南面 域北 京西 床边 门外  内里 午后 外头 左右 上下 中间 
这里要注意方位词在由它构成的名词里边所处的位置。比较：外国---国外  北城---城北 ＂外国＂指我们国家以外的＂国家＂，是一般的明词；＂国外＂指我们国家以外的空间，是表示处所的明词。两者是不同的。
２。附在别的词或者词组后边，构成表示时间或者处所的方位结构。如：
教室之外 长江以南 五个月之中 八个人以上
由方位词构成的名词或者方位结构既然是表示处所或者时间的，它们的用途也就同表示处所或者时间的名词一样，不需要再加以说明了。这里要补充说明的是，所有的名词和方位结构都不能直接作补语，必须先同介词组成介词结构，然后再由介词结构充当补语。如：酒杯要摆*在桌子上*，但算盘却要收*在抽屉里*，或者最好是在肚子里。（鲁迅，病后杂谈）

there happen to be certain differences between usages of different nouns of locality which simply have to be learned, e.g. NP +上、下、前、后、里、内、外、中、间 exist，while 东、西、南、北、左、右 cannot be used the same way, also depending on whether referring to space or time or sequence order  前、后 are used differently, similarly instead of 下, 底下 can be used more generally in the sense of "under", e.g. 棹子底下,新阅览室底下, also note compounds with 以,之

Answer (score 0):

Standard: 前面，后面，上面，下面， 左边，右边， 里面，外面。
southerners: 前面，后面，前边，后边，上面，下面，上边, 下边，左边，右边， 里面，外面，里边，外边。
Remember: 左面means on the surface of the left side of something(the wall).  右面means on the surface of right side of something.

```
1   中文楼右边就是图书馆 (should be 右边)
2   人文楼在行政楼后面吗？ (should be 后边/后面)
3   我办公室就在新阅览室下面 (should be 下边/下面)
```